# how can i route devise to certain routes and make hook work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, devise

I have the followin routes file and I basically want to link /users/id to the file placed in views/registrations/show. Now I get the error

> The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController

```
Omr::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins
  resources :pins

  devise_for :users ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  root 'pins#index'
  get 'user_root' => 'pins#index', as: :user_root
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'users_list' => 'pages#users_list'
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user

  resources :users
  resources :registrations
  post "/hook" => "registrations#hook"
  post "/registrations/:id" => "registrations#show"

  resources :courses
```

also, I think the same problem happens with the hook which is supposed to update user attributes when redirected back from paypal processed payment but doesn´t update anything in my database

> hook_path POST    /hook(.:format) registrations#hook

**registrations_controller.rb def hook looks like this**

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
  def hook
    params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @User = User.find params[:invoice]
      @User.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your new routes to users resource in following way. 
just keep the things in devise_for, that's all :

```
devise_for :users do
    post "/hook" =>  "devise/registrations#hook"
end
```

Comment: I tried                                                                                                          devise_for :users ,:controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }  do
    post "/hook" => "devise/registrations#hook"
    post "/users/:id" => "devise/registrations#show"
end                                                                                                       and I get **The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController** my controller is called **registrations_controller.rb**